# Round off in showing formatted currency output from a float number in c

Tags: c

I have written code to show currency format of a float number. Following is the code:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void showCurreny(float num);
int main()
{
    float usernum;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%f",&usernum);
    showCurreny(usernum);
    getch();
}


void showCurreny(float num)
{
    int digit;
    int digits[20];
    int n=(int)(num);
    int count=0;
    float decpart=(num-n);
    float n_decpart=decpart*100;

do {
    digit = n % 10;
    count++;
    digits[count]=digit;
    n /= 10;
} while (n > 0);

for(int i=count;i>0;i--)
{
    if(i%3==0 && count-i>=1)
        printf(",");
    printf("%d",digits[i]);
}
printf(".%d",(int)n_decpart);
}
```

Below is a sample run of the program.

```
Please enter a number: 123546.36
123,546.35
```

It looks like the program rounds off the floating point value which it should not. Where exactly I am making a mistake? Any help?

Comment: note : when `12346.06` , result `12345.6`, lost zero.

Comment: Don't use floating-point values for working with money. (Ab)use integers as fixed-precision numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need exact numbers, or just better approximations? For example, is this an application for a bank, where they seriously frown upon misplacing a single penny, or is it for a game, where a few fractions of a gold piece doesn't matter that much?

As others have written, a float is only accurate to about 7 significant decimal digits. This can vary between compilers, since the C standard doesn't exactly specify what a float is, but it usually is true. If you just need better precision, you can use double, or long double.

But if you need exact numbers, it doesn't matter which floating point type you use: float, double or even ultra-turbo-wide doubledouble. Some numbers will give rounding errors when you try to store them. It is similar to when trying to store 1/3 with a finite number of decimal digits. You will get problems like 0.10 + 0.10 not being equal to 0.20.

If you need exact numbers, you can store the amount as a number of cents (or what the local currency uses) in an integer:

```
int amount = 1405;
printf("Amount: %d.%02d\n", amount / 100, amount % 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

A `float` is only accurate to about 7 significant figures.

For better precision, use a `double`. That's good to about 15 significant figures.

Comment: Perhaps it should be added that if one wants to avoid _all_ rounding errors, as is often the case when working with money, double won't help either.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy - Then for cases like Money, do you advise another data type like long double?

Comment: Alas, long double on many platforms is no more precise than a double. You need a specific currency type: have a search on Google.

Comment: @Bathsheba - I tried searching on google, but apparently C# has a special `DECIMAL` data type for dealing with currency but according to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) , there are no special data types for this purpose. I also tried using `long long long int` for a variable and the gcc returned me an error that It is Too Long For GCC :P

Answer (score 1):

For `123546.36`:

```
The most accurate representation using float  = 1.23546359375E5
The most accurate representation using double = 1.23546360000000000582076609135E5
```

Using `float`:

```
 1.23546359375E5
-1.23546000000E5
----------------
 0.359375
```

Finally:

```
(int)(0.359375 * 100) = 35
```

As @Bathsheba say, use a `double`

Answer (score 0):

Floating Point Numbers In C Have Less Precision till only 7 significant figures. This happens due to the rounding done by the compiler. If you want to avoid this happening, use `DOUBLE` (in this case I got the output correct using `LONG DOUBLE`) rather than `FLOAT` as it has more precision than `FLOAT`. Incase you want to know why this happens with float in rounding numbers, Please give a read to the article at the following link -

[What Every Programmer Must Know About Floating Point](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Here Is the modified Source Code Which according to your comment Is giving correct answer -

```
#include<stdio.h>
void showCurreny(long double);
int main()
{
    long double usernum;
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%Lg",&usernum);
    showCurreny(usernum);

}


void showCurreny(long double num)
{
    int digit,i;
    int digits[20];
    int n=(int)(num);
    int count=0;
    long double decpart=(num-n);
    long double n_decpart=decpart*100;

do 
{
    digit = n % 10;
    count++;
    digits[count]=digit;
    n /= 10;
}while (n > 0);

for(i=count;i>0;i--)
{
    if(i%3==0 && count-i>=1)
        printf(",");
    printf("%d",digits[i]);
}
printf(".%d",(int)n_decpart);
}
```

Comment: I have changed all float values to double. Now the input 123456.36 gives correct output but still when I try for input 123456789.36, it gives me output 123,456,789.35 !

Comment: @user3099006 - Answer Modified As per your question. Also, how come your program is getting compiled after including `conio.h`? Mine is not compiling stating that the file does not exist in gcc =.=

Comment: I am compiling it with MS Visual studio 2010 and it is working fine

Comment: @user3099006 - I have earlier also tried including this file on various computers using the linux environment and it does not compile the conio.h file whereas in TUrbo C++ and Visual Studio it gets compiled.

Comment: Did you tried input 123456789.36? I am still getting 123,456,789.35 as output with your edited code.

Comment: @user3099006 - Yups, getting the exact answer without any rounding error. I am using the GCC compiler in the linux environment. Here Is my output = `blueelvis@Blueelvis:~$ gcc workspace.c
blueelvis@Blueelvis:~$ ./a.out
Please enter a number: 123456789.36
123,456,789.36`

Answer (score 0):

Recommend new approach, let `sprinf()` do the rounding.

`sprintf()` will properly round to the number of decimal places desired creating the textual output. Use whatever floating point you see fit.  There are many edge cases to consider which it handles.  Then only `,` placement code is needed.

```
void AddCommas(char *buf) {
  char *DP = strchr(buf, '.');
  if (DP == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  if (*buf == '-' || *buf == '+') {
    buf++;
  }
  int Group = 3;  // digit grouping left of the DP.
  int Len = DP - buf;
  int Commas = (Len - 1) / Group;
  memmove(&DP[Commas], DP, strlen(DP)+1);
  while (Commas > 0) {
    memmove(&DP[Commas - Group], &DP[-Group], Group);
    DP -= Group;
    Commas--;
    DP[Commas] = ',';
  }
}

// Use float, double or long double.  Adjust FLT_MAX_EXP & %.*f
void showCurreny(float num) {
  char buf[FLT_MAX_EXP * 4 / 3 + 10];  // use right sized buffer
  int DigitsAfterDP = 2;
  sprintf(buf, "%.*f", DigitsAfterDP, num);
  AddCommas(buf);
  puts(buf);
}
```

---

Aside OP's stated problem, other problems lurk:
1) negative numbers `while (n > 0)`
2) `float` numbers larger than `int`: `n=(int)(num)`
3) 64-bit `int`: `digits[20]` too small).